# DRY way of handling nested forms with Rails 4 strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I'm struggling with finding the proper and DRY way of handling nested forms when using Rails 4 strong parameters.

I have some models that I reutilize in different ways across my application and thus I have some nested forms.

The problem is when I use nested forms, I don't feel like I'm doing the DRYest approach.

Consider the following is in an `AccountsController`:

```
params.require(:account).permit(
  person_attributes: [
    :name,
    address: [
      :city
    ]
  ]
)
```

From my perspective `person_attributes` shouldn't be set in `AccountsController`.
I mean, AccountsController shouldn't know that much about `Person` class.

I thought of adding such permitted attributes to `PeopleController` but then it'd be a private method which wouldn't be directly accessible.

Now I'm thinking of storing person' permitted attributes in a class method `Person.permitted_attributes` but I'm not sure if this is a smart design decision.
Doing so I would be able to use it in several places.
I would obviously write individual tests for each controller.

I understand parameter filtering should be done in controllers, not in models, but I'm not sure whether adding code duplication is a good tradeoff.

**What do you guys think about this?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing it right. It's explicitely done that way in the [Rails guide (4.5.2)](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters). The permitted parameters regarding People in your AccountController need not be the same to the ones in your PeopleController, by the way.

> You can also use permit on nested parameters, like:

```
params.permit(:name, { emails: [] },
              friends: [ :name,
                         { family: [ :name ], hobbies: [] }])
```

> This declaration whitelists the name, emails, and friends attributes.
>   It is expected that emails will be an array of permitted scalar
>   values, and that friends will be an array of resources with specific
>   attributes: they should have a name attribute (any permitted scalar
>   values allowed), a hobbies attribute as an array of permitted scalar
>   values, and a family attribute which is restricted to having a name
>   (any permitted scalar values allowed here, too).